# How to cascade delete from a child to a parent

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_important = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reminder = models.OneToOneField(Reminder, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Reminder(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    stop_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

Basically, a Todo becomes a Reminder when a start and optional end time are supplied.

At the moment, when I delete a Reminder object, the reminder field in the Todo object is set to Null, which what I want.

## What I need to know:

How can I setup these models so that if a Todo object is deleted, the corresponding Reminder object will also be deleted?

Also, if it wasn't a one-to-one relationship, let's say it was a many-to-one (many Todo's to one Reminder) relationship, how could one setup the models so that if a Todo object was deleted, the Reminder object will also be deleted, but only if there were no more Todo objects linked to the Reminder?

Also, with regards to:

```
stop_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

If it is left blank in the form, what will the default value be, stored in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the relationship as

```
    reminder = models.OneToOneField(Reminder, blank=True, null=True,
                 on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Here you are specifying `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`. This tells django to set the field to NULL when a referenced object is deleted. If you want to delete the object too use `models.CASCADE`. Django uses this as default value.

More reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

```
stop_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
```

When nothing specified this field will not be set and will be blank, there is no default value for this.

---

As mentioned in the comment, if you want to set the reminder field in the corresponding `Todo` object to `NULL` when `Reminder` object is deleted, then you can put the `OneToOne` relationship field in `Reminder` class instead of `Todo` class.

As its onetoone relationship, as per django ORM its identical when you put in either of classes. You will access it through a attribute from both objects.

For Many-to-one you will have to use pre-post delete signal. But signals have their own limitations

Comment: I do not want to use to models.CASCADE because when a Reminder object is deleted I want to set the reminder field in the corresponding Todo object to NULL, but when a Todo object is deleted I want to delete the corresponding Reminder object. How do I setup my models to achieve this?

Comment: @OliverFunk, In that case you can set the onetoone relationship in `Reminder` class. For Many-to-one you will have to use pre-post delete signal. But signals have their own limitations.

Comment: But that seems like an unnecessary field in the Reminder object. I mean,  the relationship is defined in the Todo object already, why must I define it in the Reminder object too? That will also create another column in the database aswell, it just seems unnecessary.. Should I create a method inside the Todo object that executes when a Todo is deleted and that deletes the Reminder object associated with it?

Comment: @OliverFunk, I suggested to move relationship field to `Reminder` class.

Comment: Ah damn! I misread your comment... Your suggestion makes complete sense. Can you change your answer so that I can mark it correct?